# FW/1 ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, fw1

Hi I'm getting this error below and not sure how to resolved it.

> Detail:
>
> Either there are no methods with the specified method name and
>   argument types or the leaseService method is overloaded with argument
>   types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0
>   methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object
>   and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to
>   reduce ambiguity.
>
> Message:
>
> The leaseService method was not found.

[image]

I'm using fw1 3.1.1 and Adobe CF 9 on Windows 7 running on IIS 7.

My Framework-one structure (simplified)

Controllers
-property.cfc
-lease.cfc

Model/Beans
    -property.cfc
    -lease.cfc

Services
    -property.cfc
    -lease.cfc

Views/property
    -detail.cfm

In my property controller I'm calling lease list function like so.

```
property propertyService;
property leaseService;

function detail(rc) {
        rc.property = variables.propertyService.detail(id=rc.id);  
        rc.leases = variables.leaseService().list(propertyID=rc.id);
}
```

Here is my lease services:

```
component accessors=true {

function init( beanFactory ) {
        variables.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    return this;
}

function list(propertyID) {
        var qData = new query();
        qData.setDatasource(application.dsn); 
        qData.setName("qLease");
        qData.addParam(name="propertyID", value="#rc.propertyID#", CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_numeric");

        qData.setSQL("
            select l.id, l.fName, l.lName, l.leaseActive, l.leaseFrom, l.leaseTo, CONCAT(u.fname,' ',u.lname) pmName
        from leases l inner join users u on l.pmID = u.id
        where propertyID = :propertyID
        order by LeaseTo DESC
        ");

        qReturn = qData.execute();
        result = qReturn.getResult();

        return result;
}

}
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `leaseService` as a method. It's a variable. So instead of this:

```
rc.property = variables.propertyService.detail(id=rc.id);  
rc.leases = variables.leaseService().list(propertyID=rc.id);
```

Do this:

```
rc.property = variables.propertyService.detail(id=rc.id);  
rc.leases = variables.leaseService.list(propertyID=rc.id);
```

Note that I removed the `()`

HTH

Comment: D'oh! This is embarrassing... Thanks John for pointing that out!